# Add option to equal height plugin for time delay

Tags: jquery, plugins, jquery-plugins

I want to add a new option to the [equal height plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/sidonaldson/LsrHY/) that allows the height to be calculated after a time delay. Reason being that I have other jquery script which managed a image gallery that changes in height.

```
$.fn.extend({        
    equalHeight: function (options) {
        //set default height to 0 or auto
        var defaults = {
            height:null,
            minHeight: 0,
            maxHeight: null     
        };
        //merge options
        options = $.extend(defaults, options);
        //cache the children (is this the parent or a group of elements)
        var children = (this.length > 1) ? this : this.children();             
        if(options.height !== null){
            //if specific height is set
            children.height(options.height);
        }else{
            //set the height to auto which releases the boxes heights
            children.css('height', 'auto');
            //loop though the elements and get their heights
            children.each(function () {            
                //if bigger than the default set to default
                if ($(this).height() > options.minHeight) options.minHeight= $(this).height();
                //if maxheight is set
                if(options.maxHeight !== null){
                    if(options.minHeight > options.maxHeight) options.minHeight= options.maxHeight;
                }
            });
            //set the height on all the children
            children.height(options.minHeight);
        }
        //return this so the jQuery chain is preserved
        return this;
    }
 });
```

Comment: Why not simply have your other code re-trigger the existing plugin?

Comment: Because I would like to re-use this plugin on another website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be you should use setInterval(100):

```
setInterval(100);    
var defaults = {
            height:null,
            minHeight: 0,
            maxHeight: null     
        };
```

Or if you can catch image resize event use global variable to ensure that image resized and setInterval

--- Update

You can try this:

```
function func(obj, options) {
    //cache the children (is this the parent or a group of elements)
    var children = (obj.length > 1) ? obj: obj.children();             
    if(options.height !== null){
        //if specific height is set
        children.height(options.height);
    }else{
        //set the height to auto which releases the boxes heights
        children.css('height', 'auto');
        //loop though the elements and get their heights
        children.each(function () {            
            //if bigger than the default set to default
            if ($(obj).height() > options.minHeight) options.minHeight= $(obj).height();
            //if maxheight is set
            if(options.maxHeight !== null){
                if(options.minHeight > options.maxHeight) options.minHeight= options.maxHeight;
            }
        });
        //set the height on all the children
        children.height(options.minHeight);
    }    

    return obj;
}

//this closure reserves the $.
(function ($) {   
    $.fn.extend({        
        equalHeight: function (options) {
            //set default height to 0 or auto
            var defaults = {
                delay = false;
                delayCount = 0;
                height:null,
                minHeight: 0,
                maxHeight: null               
            };
            //merge options
            options = $.extend(defaults, options);

            //delay
            if (delay)
                return setTimeout(func, delayCount);           

        }
     });  
})(jQuery);
```

Use following to run with delay

```
$('#parent').equalHeight({ delay: true, delayCount: 100});
```

Comment: Is there a way to pass this as a jquery option?

Comment: Just update answer. Woy should think in that way if you can't trigger event from another plugin. Alternative, you can check image size on page load and in extent check if size was changed.

Comment: brilliant thanks, I was having the problem with the $this when inside of the setTimeout.